# Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 2.9.1 or later

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 2.9.1 or later.
is there not any way to upload the build with 5.1.1? i dont want to upload with xcode 6 for now

Comment: download Application Loader https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to submit the build using Xcode 5.1.1 and everything worked fine (I've submitted the build from the Organizer). You just need to wait for a while before the build appears in the iTunes Connect.

Comment: how long did you wait to see the binary accepted in this new layout?

Comment: about 5-10 minutes usually

Answer (score 5):

I was confused about this because I had already uploaded the build through Xcode. The problem was that Apple can take some time 'processing' the upload and until then, the blue 'plus' button will not appear. Once processing is done, on iTunes connect you will see the following view. Click the plus, and a radio chooser pops up, showing your uploaded build. 
[image: iTunesConnect.PlusBuildMagicallyAppears]